# Initialize MySQL data in Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I tried to create Node.js Container and MySQL Container by docker-compose, so I wrote below files.

○`tree`

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── mysql
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── conf
│   │   ├── default_authentication.cnf
│   │   └── my.cnf
│   ├── data
│   └── init
│       └── create.sql
└── nodejs
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── app
```

○./docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  webserver:
    build: nodejs
    image: node-express-dev:1.0
    container_name: nodejs
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs/app:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
  db:
    build: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - dbata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql
volumes:
  dbata:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/.../mysql/data
      o: bind
```

○./mysql/Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:latest

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/mysql/

RUN touch /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
```

○./mysql/init/create.sql

```
SET CHARSET UTF8;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;

use test;

SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = utf8;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION = utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE users(
id INT,
name VARCHAR(20),
byear INT
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'user1', 1995);
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'user2', 1995);

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user';
```

Then I use `sudo docker-compose up --build -d` and access to MySQL by `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u user -p`. And in database `test` I INSERT one tuple to users table.

I thought `./mysql/init/create.sql` is executed whenever I run `sudo docker-compose up --build -d`, so once I remove containers by `sudo docker-compose down` and recreate containers by `sudo docker-compose up --build -d`. But when I checked `test.users`, there are three tuples(create.sql inserts TWO tuples).

My thought (`./mysql/init/create.sql` is executed whenever I run `sudo docker-compose up --build -d`) is wrong?

Comment: docker-compose stop won't remove your containers, just stop them :)

Comment: Sorry I missed to write. I run `sudo docker-compose down`.

Comment: 1) Init scripts are executed each time the container starts 2) `docker-compose down` doesn't remove containers

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/

these docs say containers are removed with docker-compose down, dont they?

Comment: @emix When I use `docker-compose down` output is `stopping ~` and `removing ~`, so I thought container is removed. Is it wrong or how should I do to remove container.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I confused the `down` with `stop`. Anyway, you have no volumes, you're using custom data in the docker-compose volume mounts `- ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql`. Remove the `mysql/data` directory and the mount. Why you need that anyway? Use a named volume instead: `- db:/var/lib/mysql` and it will work as expected. If you want to keep the data in your local directory, then you have to remove it's contents after you bring the containers down `rm -rf mysql/data/*`

Comment: I checked `create.sql` file in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, and contents are fixed if I do down -> fix mysql/init/create.sql -> up.

Comment: @emix Thanks. I try to persistence mysql data, so I create local directory to contain container's data.

Comment: A named volume will also persist your data. Just don't use `down`, but `stop` instead so the volume is not removed. Docker never removes one's data.

Answer (score 3):

The scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are only run if the MySQL data directory doesn't exist and the container is being launched to actually run `mysqld`.  See [this part of the entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L94) and "Initializing a fresh instance" in [the image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

If you want to re-run it, you need to cause Docker Compose to delete and recreate the data volume.  I believe `docker-compose rm` will do it; simply `down` and `up` won't.

(If your application has a more sophisticated migration system, it seems to be fairly common to run the migrations in an entrypoint script, and I feel like the SO examples I've seen recently have all been around the Python Django framework, though beyond the specific command it's a useful generic technique.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line

```
COPY create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

into your `Dockerfile`.